Build step 'Docker Build and Publish' marked build as failure
i tried to re-install plugins and to upgrade them but no result. until now i don't know what is the problem or where i need to check. Also check the file that this line of code (org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.DockerRegistryToken$1.call(DockerRegistryToken.java:147)) read from but everything is right .
Error

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and edit your question accordingly.

What does the JSON object look like?
